# SQL Error: ORA-00905: missing keyword 00905. 00000 - "missing keyword" when using case

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a sql query which is

```
select * 
from ext_policysummary
where policydetail_id <> 'nan'
and case when '10-04-21' = '12-04-21'
then  partition_data = to_date('10-04-21','DD-MM-YYYY')
and RIGHT('0' + CAST(partition_hour AS VARCHAR(10)), 2) between cast('10-04-21' as varchar(10)) and cast('12-04-21' as varchar(10))
else partition_data = to_date('10-04-21','DD-MM-YYYY') and RIGHT('0' + CAST(partition_hour AS VARCHAR(10)),2) >= cast(partition_hour as varchar(20))
or (partition_data = to_date('12-04-21','DD-MM-YYYY') and RIGHT('0' + CAST(partition_hour AS VARCHAR(10)),2) <= cast(partition_hour as varchar(10)))
or  (partition_data > to_date('10-04-21','DD-MM-YYYY') and partition_date < to_date('12-04-21','DD-MM-YYYY')) end
```

I am getting an error SQL Error: ORA-00905: missing keyword
00905. 00000 -  "missing keyword"

Can anyone please suggest me where i am going wrong.

Thanks

Comment: Can you explain what the condition is supposed to do?

Comment: In SQL (and Oracle) the string concatenation operator is `||` not `+`

Comment: `cast('12-04-21' as varchar(10))` can be simplified to `'12-04-21'`

Comment: `then  partition_data = to_date('10-04-21','DD-MM-YYYY')` - not sure if you can set the value there...